# Setting modals size to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have created a modal inside a `button-container` which utilizes some `flex` display elements.

**The problem occurs** when I want to size the `.modal-mask` to a 100% of width/height to the whole page (`body`) size which is my goal here, I can't seem to get it to adjust properly without disturbing my `button-container` elements.

In short, I want the inner div `.modal-mask` to be sized 100% to the body

**Project Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/est857q0/

**HTML:**

```
  <ul id="button-container">
  <li>
    <a id="html-modal-button" @click="showModal = 'html-modal'">
                        <img class="htmllogo" src="http://sweettutos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/placeholder.png">
                    </a>
    <htmlmodal v-if="showModal === 'html-modal'" @close="showModal = false"></htmlmodal>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a id="cs-modal-button" @click="showModal = 'cs-modal'">
                    <img class="csharplogo" src="http://sweettutos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/placeholder.png"> 
                    </a>
    <csmodal v-if="showModal === 'cs-modal'" @close="showModal = false"></csmodal>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- MODAL SECTION -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="html-modal-template">
                <transition name="html-modal">
                        <div class="modal-mask">
                            <div class="modal-wrapper">
                                <div class="modal-container">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <slot name="body">
                                            <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">HTML CLOSE</button>
                                        </slot>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </transition>
            </script>

            <script type="text/x-template" id="cs-modal-template">
                <transition name="cs-modal">
                        <div class="modal-mask">
                            <div class="modal-wrapper">
                                <div class="modal-container">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <slot name="body">
                                            <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">CS CLOSE</button>
                                        </slot>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </transition>
            </script>
```

**CSS:**

```
    /*Global*/

html {
  margin-right: calc(100% - 100vw);
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url('../images/wallpaper.jpg');
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

*::selection {
  background-color: red;
}

/*Header*/

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 4vh;
}

/*Containers*/

#button-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 40vh;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
  width: 90vw;
  height: 45vh;
  align-items: baseline;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, #fff 33%, #fff 66%, transparent 100%);
}

#button-container li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button-container .html-text-block,
.cs-text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1), transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

#button-container .htmllogo,
#button-container .csharplogo {
  width: 150px;
}

#button-container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* THE MODAL CSS SECTION */

/*Main Modal container*/

.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


.modal-content {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I attempted to set the `button-container` too 100% : https://jsfiddle.net/est857q0/ yet this messes up the flow

Comment: I don't nothing wrong with all that, how about you include a preview of how it looks, and how it should look.

Comment: can you show the html for the modal container?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I want to size the inner div .modal-mask to 100% of the body yet right now when it is 100% of width/height its only of the button-container size

Comment: I don't understand, you'll have to include a preview, of how you want it  to be

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa if you look at this https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/mwLbw11k/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=mwLbw11k when the modal is open the content behind the modal goes dark, for me the dark area is held inside the .modal-mask which is sizing to button-container, i need to find out how i could get it to size to the page body size

Comment: You should put your modal before the closing `</body>` tag - don't nest it in anything else. It's good practice to have modals on the root level of the DOM so you don't run into z-index and sizing issues

Comment: @Shayer, try adding this your modal-mask class: `width: 120%;
    height: 200%;
    margin-top: -10%;
    margin-left: -10%;`